# Looking for a good entrance point to client-server applications

Tags: frameworks, client-server, platform

I am looking for a recommendation for a good entrance point for building a client-server application.

The target developers will be students in a course (with at least basic knowledge and experience in programing but not necessarily in the client-server world).

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
A suggestion could be a platform (e.g. [node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs), [google app engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine)), programming language, framework, enviorment or anything else that you can think of.

Preferably, I am looking for the following:

- Should work in linux environment.
- Easy to learn.
- Widely used (for available examples online...).
- Open source.
- Allows to quickly build a prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went with [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/).
As I needed:

- It works in a linux environment.
- Is easy to learn.
- Has great manual and examples.
- Is open source.
- Allows to quickly build a prototype from a template or using a [manual](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList)